# Datetimepicker does only work with Input field, not Asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

My bootstrap datetimepicker does only work with the input tag like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
```

Is it possible to convert it to the asp:TextBox, because i need to use the control when operating with the database. Right now i got:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="CheckinLabel" runat="server" Text="Check- in Date"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker1" runat="server" CSSclass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="CheckoutLabel" runat="server" Text="Check-out Date"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker2" runat="server" CSSclass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
                $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',

                });
                $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',

                });
                $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
                });
                $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I'm asking this because when using the input and put the runat="server" on , i get errors because of the controlId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` as an attribute or in web.config. That will keep your IDs from changing.

You have 3 options:

1.) control attribute
2.) page level setting
3.) attribute on `pages` element in web.config

Comment: Works.. if i should put it in the config file... what should be around it?

Comment: @Mikkel, updated. If you want to do it in config. simply add this attribute on the `pages` element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also target it with it's own css class name.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CheckoutLabel" runat="server" Text="Check-out Date" CssClass="myClassName"></asp:TextBox>
```

$(".myClassName").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',

```
            });
```